# PyQt5 button to run function and update LCD

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am getting started with creating GUI's in PyQt5 with Python 3.  At the click of the button I want to run the "randomint" function and display the returned integer to the QLCDNumber named "lcd".

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLCDNumber
from random import randint


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initui()

    def initui(self):
        lcd = QLCDNumber(self)

        button = QPushButton('Generate', self)
        button.resize(button.sizeHint())

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(lcd)
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        button.clicked.connect(lcd.display(self.randomint()))

        self.setGeometry(300, 500, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Rand Integer')
        self.show()

    def randomint(self):
        random = randint(2, 99)
        return random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am getting the output:

> TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

How can I get the LCD to display the output from function "randomint"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `button.clicked.connect` expects the slot (Python callable object), but `lcd.display` returns `None`. So we need a simple function (slot) for `button.clicked.connect` which will display your newly generated value. This is working version:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLCDNumber
from random import randint


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initui()


    def initui(self):
        self.lcd = QLCDNumber(self)

        button = QPushButton('Generate', self)
        button.resize(button.sizeHint())

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.lcd)
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

        self.setGeometry(300, 500, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Rand Integer')
        self.show()


    def handleButton(self):
        self.lcd.display(self.randomint())


    def randomint(self):
        random = randint(2, 99)
        return random


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of resolving the `TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType` is to prefix your slot with `lambda:` like so:

```
self.tableWidget.cellChanged['int','int'].connect(lambda:self.somefunction())
```

I actually don't know *why* but it's a solution that worked for me.